# Find content of one file from another file in UNIX

Tags: file, grep

I have 2 files. First file contains the list of row ID's of tuples of a table in the database.
And second file contains SQL queries with these row ID's in "where" clause of the query.

For example:

File 1

```
1610657303
1610658464
1610659169
1610668135
1610668350
1610670407
1610671066
```

File 2

```
update TABLE_X set ATTRIBUTE_A=87 where ri=1610668350;
update TABLE_X set ATTRIBUTE_A=87 where ri=1610672154;
update TABLE_X set ATTRIBUTE_A=87 where ri=1610668135;
update TABLE_X set ATTRIBUTE_A=87 where ri=1610672153;
```

I have to read File 1 and search in File 2 for all the SQL commands which matches the row ID's from File 1 and dump those SQL queries in a third file.

File 1 has 1,00,000 entries and File 2 contains 10 times the entries of File 1 i.e. 1,00,0000.

I used `grep -f File_1 File_2 > File_3`. But this is extremely slow and the rate is 1000 entries per hour.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: Do all queries which use the row IDs mentioned in file 1 end up in the same output file, or do you want to have a separate file for each row ID in file 1?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the files on the IDs?  Or does the order have to be preserved?

Comment: Just one output file.

Each time an entry from File 1 matches an entry in File 2, that entry of File 2 should be dumped in an output file. And the entries in File 1 and File 2 are unique. No duplicate lines in any of the files.

Comment: @fizzer Order doesn't matter. We can sort it.

Comment: You probably mean 1,000,000 and 10,000,000 right ? :-)

Comment: Just tried the `grep -f` approach. Had to kill grep before it ate all my RAM :) What about importing data into a couple of SQL tables and letting sqlite or mysql handle the search ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for `grep -f file1 file 2` . It works for me. I have 3 million rows and it works.

Comment: Sorting just the IDs used as the strings to find dramatically improves performance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk -v FS="[ =]" 'NR==FNR{rows[$1]++;next}(substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1) in rows)' File1 File2
```

This should be pretty quick. On my machine, it took under 2 seconds to create a lookup of 1 million entries and compare it against 3 million lines.

**Machine Specs:**

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz (8 cores)
98 GB RAM
```

Comment: This one-liner is brilliant :)

Comment: If you're going to specify the time it takes to run the command, might be relevant to include the machine specs.

Comment: Your machine's a beast. Btw if you add `;` to FS i.e. `FS="[ =;]"`, you can simply use `$(NF-1)` to get the numbers w/o `substr` and co. Not sure how it'd impact performance though.

Comment: @doubleDown It's not my personal machine :) It's my test box at workplace. True we can do that too .. just didn't feel like cramming too many Field separators.

Comment: @JS웃 This one is awsome.
 Total time consumed on my machine was 46 minutes.

 Machine Specs:
 SunOS 5.10 Generic_127111-03 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120

     Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What if for a key in file 1, there are multiple different entries in file 2?

Answer (score 69):

You don't need regexps, so `grep -F -f file1 file2`

Comment: The OP says he's already tried this one, but it was too slow.

Comment: I'm kinda interested how this pits against [JS웃's awk solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17236091/1743811) but I'm too lazy to replicate the OP's condition.

Comment: On my machine: grep => 38.4s real; awk => 53.8s real; file1 19^6 rows, file2 10^7 rows.

Comment: I performed the same test on my machine and results are pretty good with grep -F, it is important to note that -F(captial) Interpret the pattern as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched which is why is extremely fast as compared to awk or regular grep with just -f. Hope this helps !!

Comment: I timed the test (time grep -F -f file1 file2) and adding the -F cut the time by a factor of 10 for my limited test set.

Comment: Worth mentioning, make sure both files have Unix EOL. I received the files from Windows with \r\n line endings and the command was not providing the expected result until I realized I need to do EOL conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a programming language such as Perl, Ruby or Python.

In Ruby, a solution reading both files (`f1` and `f2`) just once could be:

```
idxes = File.readlines('f1').map(&:chomp)

File.foreach('f2') do | line |
  next unless line =~ /where ri=(\d+);$/
  puts line if idxes.include? $1
end
```

or with Perl

```
open $file, '<', 'f1';
while (<$file>) { chomp; $idxs{$_} = 1; }
close($file);

open $file, '<', 'f2';
while (<$file>) {
    next unless $_ =~ /where ri=(\d+);$/;
    print $_ if $idxs{$1};
}
close $file;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of previous answers are correct but the only thing that worked for me was this command

```
grep -oi -f a.txt b.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but wouldn't it be sufficient to just iterate the IDs in `file1` and for each ID, grep `file2` and store the matches in a third file? I.e.

```
 for ID in `cat file1`; do grep $ID file2; done > file3
```

This is not terribly efficient (since file2 will be read over and over again), but it may be good enough for you. If you want more speed, I'd suggest to use a more powerful scripting language which lets you read `file2` into a map which quickly allows identifying lines for a given ID.

Here's a Python version of this idea:

```
queryByID = {}

for line in file('file2'):
  lastEquals = line.rfind('=')
  semicolon = line.find(';', lastEquals)
  id = line[lastEquals + 1:semicolon]
  queryByID[id] = line.rstrip()

for line in file('file1'):
  id = line.rstrip()
  if id in queryByID:
    print queryByID[id]
```

Comment: I used perl too, but it didn't help:

my $input_ri_file="input_RI.csv";

my $input_sql_file="SQL_file.sql";
my $output_sql_file = "Out_SQL_file.sql";

open (SQLFILE, "<$input_sql_file");
foreach(<SQLFILE>){
  push @ lin,$_ unless ($_ eq "\n");
}
close $SQLFILE;

open (RILIST, "<$input_ri_file");
foreach(<RILIST>){
  push @ ri_list,$_ unless ($_ eq "\n");
}
close $RILIST;

open (FINALSQLFILE, ">$output_sql_file");

foreach $ri (@ ri_list){
  chomp $ri;
  for (@ lin) {
    if ($_ =~ /$ri/ ) {  
      print FINALSQLFILE $_; 
    }
  }  
} 

close FINALSQLFILE;

Comment: @Tirthankar: I just added a Python version, does that help? The script expects two files `file1` and `file2`. It prints the matches to the standard output, so you can redirect that to a file.

Comment: @Tirthankar you might want to use pastebin instead of dumping code into a comment... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The awk/grep solutions mentioned above were slow or memory hungry on my machine (file1 10^6 rows, file2 10^7 rows). So I came up with an SQL solution using sqlite3.

Turn file2 into a CSV-formatted file where the first field is the value after `ri=`

```
cat file2.txt  | gawk -F= '{ print $3","$0 }' | sed 's/;,/,/' > file2_with_ids.txt
```

Create two tables:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE file1(rowId char(10));
sqlite> CREATE TABLE file2(rowId char(10), statement varchar(200));
```

Import the row IDs from file1:

```
sqlite> .import file1.txt file1
```

Import the statements from file2, using the "prepared" version:

```
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .import file2_with_ids.txt file2
```

Select all and ony the statements in table `file2` with a matching rowId in table `file1`:

```
sqlite> SELECT statement FROM file2 WHERE file2.rowId IN (SELECT file1.rowId FROM file1);
```

File 3 can be easily created by redirecting output to a file before issuing the select statement:

```
sqlite> .output file3.txt
```

Test data:

```
sqlite> select count(*) from file1;
1000000
sqlite> select count(*) from file2;
10000000
sqlite> select * from file1 limit 4;
1610666927
1610661782
1610659837
1610664855
sqlite> select * from file2 limit 4;
1610665680|update TABLE_X set ATTRIBUTE_A=87 where ri=1610665680;
1610661907|update TABLE_X set ATTRIBUTE_A=87 where ri=1610661907;
1610659801|update TABLE_X set ATTRIBUTE_A=87 where ri=1610659801;
1610670610|update TABLE_X set ATTRIBUTE_A=87 where ri=1610670610;
```

Without creating any indices, the select statement took about 15 secs on an AMD A8 1.8HGz 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try AWK and use number from file 1 as a key for example simple script

First script will produce awk script:
awk -f script1.awk

```
 {
   print "\$0 ~ ",$0,"{ print \$0 }" > script2.awk;
 }
```

and then invoke script2.awk with file

Comment: But this will also incur multiple file reads on both file 1 and file 2. Don't you think this will also be slower.

Comment: Yes, but if you read your file1 once and create one big regexp and then check all lines in file2 agains this regexp it would read each file only once.

Answer (score -1):

## reports any lines contained in < file 1> missing in < file 2>

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(cat < file 1>); 
do ((\!$(grep -F -c -- "$a" < file 2>))) && echo $a; 
done && unset IFS
```

or to do what the asker wants, take off the negation and redirect

```
(IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(cat < file 1>); 
do (($(grep -F -c -- "$a" < file 2>))) && echo $a; 
done && unset IFS) >> < file 3>
```

Comment: You can see a shell script I recently made that does this at my blog: http://scriptsandoneliners.blogspot.com/2014/08/blog-post.html