# Query the contents of a file using another file in AWK

Tags: awk, logic, conditional-statements

I am trying to conditionally filter a file based on values in a second file. File1 contains numbers and File2 contains two columns of numbers. The question is to filter out those rows in file1 which fall within the range denoted in each row of file2.

I have a series of loops which works, but takes >12hrs to run depending on the lengths of both files. This code is noted below. Alternatively, I have tried to use awk, and looked at other questions posted on slack overflow, but I cannot figure out how to change the code appropriately.

Loop method:

```
while IFS= read READ
            do  
                position=$(echo $READ | awk '{print $4}')
                    while IFS= read BED
                        do
                            St=$(echo $BED | awk '{print $2}')
                            En=$(echo $BED | awk '{print $3}')
                        if (($position < "$St"))
                            then
                                break 
                        else 
                            if (($position >= "$St" && $position <= "$En"));
                                then 
                                    echo "$READ" | awk '{print $0"\t EXON"}' >> outputfile
                            fi  
                        fi
                        done < file2
            done < file1
```

Blogs with similar questions:

[awk: filter a file with another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694046/awk-filter-a-file-with-another-file)

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($2 in a)' d3_tmp FS="[ \t=]" m2p_tmp
```

[Find content of one file from another file in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234071/find-content-of-one-file-from-another-file-in-unix)

```
awk -v FS="[ =]" 'NR==FNR{rows[$1]++;next}(substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1) in rows)' File1 File2
```

file1: (tab delimited)

```
AAA BBB 1500
CCC DDD 2500
EEE FFF 2000
```

file2: (tab delimited)

```
GGG 1250 1750
HHH 1950 2300
III 2600 2700
```

Expected output would retain rows 1 and 3 from file1 (in a new file, file3) because these records fall within the ranges of row 1 columns 2 and 3,  and row 2 columns 2 and columns 3 of file2. In the actual files, they're not row restricted i.e. I am not wanting to look at row1 of file1 and compare to row1 of file2, but compare row1 to all rows in file2 to get the hit.

file3 (output)

```
AAA BBB 1500
EEE FFF 2000
```

Comment: additional codes used after looking at those blogs listed include: 

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} (($3 < $NF && $3 > $NF-1) in a)' file2.txt FS="[ \t]" file1.txt
```

Comment: How big are files 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[i]=$2;b[i++]=$3;next}{for(j=0;j<i;j++){if ($3>=a[j] && $3<=b[j]){print;}}}' i=0 file2 file1
AAA BBB 1500
EEE FFF 2000
```

Read the `file2` contents and store it in arrays `a` and `b`. When `file1` is read, check for the number to be between the entire `a` and `b` arrays and print.

One more option:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=$2;i<=$3;i++)a[i];next}($3 in a)'  file2 file1
AAA BBB 1500
EEE FFF 2000
```

`File2` is read and the entire range of numbers is broken up and stored into the associate array `a`. When we read the `file1`, we just need to lookup the array `a`.

Comment: brilliant, this was the logic I had in my head and I was telling myself I would have to load each column if file2 into an array of its own (like in your first option)

In addition, if there was an additional column in file2 that would be helpful annotation how could I change the code to print the file1 line but append the column from file2 to that line. for example:

awk 'NR==FNR{a[i]=$2;b[i++]=$3;c[i++]=$4;next} 

this would add the other column into its own array, i assume the [i++] logic is correct?

then, 

if ($3>=a[j] && $3<=b[j]){print"\t"c[j];}}}'

Comment: in this case, you should do `i++` only in `c` . If this answer had worked for you, please accept it.

Comment: awk 'NR==FNR{a[i]=$2;b[i]=$3;c[i++]=$4;next}{for(j=0;j<i;j++){if ($4>=a[j] && $4<=b[j]){OFS="\t"; $15=c[j]; print$0;}}}' i=0  file2 file1 > file3

Answer (score 0):

Another awk. It may or may not make sense depending on the filesizes:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$3]=$2                    # hash file2 records, $3 is key, $2 value
    next
}
{
    for(i in a)                 # for each record in file1 go thru ever element in a
        if($3<=i && $3>=a[i]) { # if it falls between
            print               # output
            break               # exit loop once match found
        }
}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
AAA BBB 1500
EEE FFF 2000
```